# haystack search not indexing multivaluefield django

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-models, django-haystack

I am trying to use manytomanyfield for fetch searching but when I am trying to update index, it shows no attribute error

```
#search_index.py
class ProductCreateModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True,template_name='search/indexes/catalogue/product_text.txt')
user = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user',faceted=True )
title = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')
description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description',null = True)
category = indexes.CharField(model_attr='category',faceted=True )
brand = indexes.CharField(model_attr='brand_name',faceted=True )
availability_regions = indexes.MultiValueField(faceted=True )
model = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='model_name',null = True)
    def prepare_availability_regions(self, obj):
    return [ availability_regions.name for a in obj.availability_regions_set.all()]
```

when I am trying to update it shows me this

```
return [ availability_regions.name for a in obj.availability_regions_set.all()]
AttributeError: 'ProductCreateModel' object has no attribute 'availability_regions_set'
```

here is my product_text.txt

```
{{object.title}}
{% for a in availability_regions %}
   {{ a }}
{% endfor %}
{{object.category}}
{{object.model_name}}
{{object.brand_name}}
{{ object.description|default:"" }}
```

I just follow the tutoria, I don't know how to do it in right way, would you tell me the right way to do it and where can i find the documentation of this ?